# Count occurrence of element in column of lists panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that has a column of lists of strings, I want to find the number of occurrences of a string in the column.

i.e

```
         samples  subject  trial_num
0    ['aa','bb']        1          1
1    ['bb','cc']        1          2
```

I want to get 2 for 'bb' 1 for 'aa' and 'cc'

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
df['samples'].explode().value_counts().to_dict()
#{'bb': 2, 'aa': 1, 'cc': 1}
```

Or without `explode`:

```
pd.Series(np.concatenate(df['samples'])).value_counts().to_dict()
#{'bb': 2, 'aa': 1, 'cc': 1}
```

Solution only with **numpy**

```
dict(zip(*np.unique(np.concatenate(df['samples']), return_counts=True)))
#{'bb': 2, 'aa': 1, 'cc': 1}
```